# XSLT Transformation not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT I am trying to get working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="Sample">
<!-- Get the Sample ID once and from the Name attribute and set it to a variable -->
<xsl:variable name="SampleID" select="Sample/Name"/>

<INBOUND>



    <xsl:for-each select="Element">
    <INBOX_SAMPLE>
      <EVENT></EVENT>
      <SAMPLE_ID>'<xsl:value-of select="$SampleID"/>'</SAMPLE_ID>
      <PARAMETER_NAME>'<xsl:value-of select='substring(//ID,1,1)'/>'</PARAMETER_NAME>
      <SRESULT>'<xsl:value-of select="PPM"/>'</SRESULT>
    </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  </xsl:for-each>



</INBOUND>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the following XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Sample>
    <Name>2015001943 7</Name>
    <AnalysisDate>3/1/2015 10:54:26 AM</AnalysisDate>
    <Element>
             <ID>Hydrogen</ID>
             <PPM>17.061</PPM>
        </Element>
    <Element>
             <ID>Nitrogen</ID>
             <PPM>21</PPM>
        </Element>
    <Element>
             <ID>Oxygen</ID>
             <PPM>312</PPM>
        </Element>
</Sample>
```

When I run the XSLT I it will step over each element Node, but the ID is not changing.  This is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><INBOUND><INBOX_SAMPLE><EVENT /><SAMPLE_ID>''</SAMPLE_ID><PARAMETER_NAME>'H'</PARAMETER_NAME><SRESULT>'17.061'</SRESULT></INBOX_SAMPLE><INBOX_SAMPLE><EVENT /><SAMPLE_ID>''</SAMPLE_ID><PARAMETER_NAME>'H'</PARAMETER_NAME><SRESULT>'21'</SRESULT></INBOX_SAMPLE><INBOX_SAMPLE><EVENT /><SAMPLE_ID>''</SAMPLE_ID><PARAMETER_NAME>'H'</PARAMETER_NAME><SRESULT>'312'</SRESULT></INBOX_SAMPLE></INBOUND>
```

I need help in a couple of places.  As you can see in the output, the `<SRESULT>` for each element is displayed, but the `<PARAMETER_NAME>` doesn't change from the 'H', what am I doing wrong.  Also, how do I put the `<SAMPLE_ID>` in for each parameter?  It is only displayed once in the original XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your XPath is incorrect, you search for `Sample/Name` but you are already in `Sample`. Change

```
<xsl:variable name="SampleID" select="Sample/Name"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="SampleID" select="Name"/>
```

Also, if you are talking of the other `ID` this line

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring(//ID,1,1)'/>
```

should be changed to

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring(ID,1,1)'/>
```

else it will select all the `ID` in the xml document.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I keep plugging away at it and found that removing the // in front of the ID worked.  Thanks for the help on the XPath, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Where you write

```
substring(//ID,1,1)
```

the //ID selects all the ID elements in the whole document. In XSLT 2.0 applying substring() to a set of (>1) nodes is an error; in XSLT 1.0 it simply takes the first node in the set. So of course it selects the first ID each time.

You want the ID of the element you are processing, which is

```
substring(ID, 1, 1)
```

Can't imagine why you thought "//" was needed here.